# Laplace transform vanishing at all integers

Tags: calculus, integration, laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

I am looking to find a function $f$ which is  not zero almost everywhere ($f\neq 0 ~a.e.$) and such that $$ \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(t) e^{-ts} dt = 0~\forall s\in\mathbb{Z}$$

I was thinking of taking an inverse Laplace transform of sine to help me with this, but apparently it does not exist. I am not thinking it should be a more elaborate construction, perhaps some sort of piecewise function.

Comment: What about $f(t)=0$?

Comment: $f\equiv 0$ is such a function.

Comment: I am sorry, I should have specified that I am excluding the trivial case.

Comment: $f=0$ almost everywhere suffices then.

Comment: Do you mean to say that it is $0$ exactly at the integers (i.e. only on integers?)

Comment: Isn't the Laplace Transform bijective? The function $f(t)=0$ is the only solution in this case.

Comment: It must be zero at the integers, but it must not be zero almost everywhere.

Comment: @statwanderer That's simply not possible.

Comment: I think if $s$ was in some open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ we could conclude that the only choice would be the zero function $a.s.$. But in this case, I think it's possible to find an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP made it more or less clear that we are dealing with the bilateral Laplace transform.

It follows from the Cauchy integral theorem that $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(t+2i\pi)^2} e^{-st}dt=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-t^2} e^{-s(t-2i\pi)}dt$$

whence take $$f(t)=e^{-t^2}-e^{-(t+2i\pi)^2}$$

Comment: So the assumption that $s$ is an integer is unnecessary then.

Comment: $e^{s2i\pi} = 1$ when $s$ is an integer

Comment: Could you point what do you mean by the Cauchy integral theorem? I am not quite sure I am familiar with its statement and implications. Also, my exponent was $e^{st}$ not $e^{-st}$.

Comment: The Laplace transform is with $e ^{-st}$ and obviously it doesn't change anything (change of variable $t\to -u$).

Comment: This is the same argument as the one you need to find the Laplace/Fourier transform of $e^{-t^2}$. For $a$ real (from $\tau =t+a$) we have $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(t+a)^2} e^{-st}dt=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-t^2} e^{-s(t-a)}dt= e^{as}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-t^2} e^{-st}dt$. Both sides are analytic in $a$ complex, thus that they are equal for $a\in \Bbb{R}$ implies they are equal for $a\in \Bbb{C}$.

Comment: In your last comment in the last sentence, what result do you use to show the implication? I mean what result shows that if $f,g$ are analytic in $a$, then if $f(a) = g(a)$ for $a \in \mathbb{R}$ then $f(a) = g(a)$ for $a \in \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Those are the key ideas of **complex analysis**. Here it is not too hard to show that $f,g$ are equal everywhere to their Taylor series at $0$, the equality on the real line implies that all the derivatives of $f,g$ at $0$ are equal, so the Taylor series are the same.

Comment: When the convergence of the Taylor series is only known on some disk we get the equality on that disk and we need to extend inductively to the neighboring disks, the key idea of **analytic continuation**.